# Hibernate doesn't store objects in one table

Tags: java, hibernate

Good evening,

trying simple things in Hibernate but for some reason Hibernate doesn't store objects in one table.
I think the reason is the table itself; the primary key of that column is of type String since the values will be unique.

Log4j doesn't give an obvious hint. Thanks for helping a newbie :-)

```
package entity;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="Vehicle")
public class Vehicle {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "Id")
private Long id;
@Column(name = "Make")
private String make;
@Column(name = "Model")
private String model;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="Vehicle_Category", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="Vehicle_Id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="Category_Name"))
private Category category;


package entity;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="Category")
public class Category {
@Id
@Column(name = "Name", unique = true)
private String name;
@Column(name="Description")
private String description;


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    EntityManagerFactory entitymanagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "hsqldb" );
    EntityManager entitymanager = entitymanagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    entitymanager.getTransaction().begin();

    /*Vehicle v1 = new Vehicle();
    v1.setMake("VW");
    v1.setModel("Golf VI");
    entitymanager.persist(v1);*/
    Category c1 = new Category();
    c1.setName("A");
    System.out.println(c1.toString());
    Category c2 = new Category();
    c2.setName("B");
    System.out.println(c2.toString());
    Category c3 = new Category();
    c3.setName("BE");
    System.out.println(c3.toString());

    entitymanager.getTransaction().commit();
    entitymanager.close();
    entitymanagerFactory.close();

}
```

The db and the tables will be created. I can even persist vehicle objects but no category objects.

as usual thanks for help!

Comment: You never call `entitymanager.persist` on any of the objects you created. (Unlike the code you commented out where you created and persisted a vehicle.)

Comment: my bad you are so right!!! thank you much.

Comment: another question why the hell IntelliJ doesn't show my db file in my specified location??? If I go with the Finder to that location I can see the files... strange